How can I update user Profile Photo using UPN(User Principal Name) using Graph API in C#
I tried with UserID and that is works perfect but when I am trying with userPrincipalName then it is not working.
public async Task<bool> UpdateProfilePicture(string userId, string imagePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await GraphClient.Users[userId].Photo.Content.PutAsync(stream);
            Console.WriteLine("Profile picture updated successfully.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (ODataError odataError)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OData error details:");
        Console.WriteLine($"Code: {odataError.Error?.Code}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {odataError.Error?.Message}");
        throw;
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error updating profile picture: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}


If I tried with userPrincipalName then is it not works.

Initially I got the same error:

To resolve the error to update profile photo of user by passing UPN, you need to get user by UPN by passing below code snippet:
Var user = await GraphClient.Users[userPrincipalName].GetAsync();

To update the user's profile picture by passing UPN, modify the code like below:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var tenantId = "XXX";
            var clientId = "XXX";
            var clientSecret = "XXX";
            GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateProfilePictureByUPN(string userPrincipalName, string imagePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    // Get user by UPN
                    var user = await GraphClient.Users[userPrincipalName].GetAsync();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        // Update profile picture
                        await GraphClient.Users[user.Id].Photo.Content.PutAsync(stream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Profile picture updated successfully.");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"User with UPN '{userPrincipalName}' not found.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"OData error details:");
                Console.WriteLine($"Code: {odataError.Error?.Code}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message: {odataError.Error?.Message}");
                throw;
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error updating profile picture: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handler = new GraphHandler();
            var userPrincipalName = "rukminitest@XXX.onmicrosoft.com"; // Replace with the desired user's UPN
            await handler.UpdateProfilePictureByUPN(userPrincipalName, "C:\\Users\\rukmini\\Downloads\\ruk.jpg");
        }
    }
}


The profile picture updated successfully like below:

